# Regex; Why is here a between difference \p{Katakana} and \x{30A0}-\x{30FF}?

Tags: regex

I found that `ー`, `゠` and `・` are not detected with `\p{Katakana}` but as range `\x{30A0}-\x{30FF}`.

See https://regex101.com/r/PZzTLm/1 and http://www.rikai.com/library/kanjitables/kanji_codes.unicode.shtml

I can't find anything on this. Does anyone have a source that explains why these characters are not included? The problem is not unique to `\p{Katakana}`. `\p{Hiragana}` and others have similar issues.

Comment: In `\p{Katakana}`, `\x{30A1}-\x{30FA}\x{30FD}-\x{30FF}` is used instead, and excludes [`\x{30A0}`, `\x{30FB}`, `\x{30FC}`](https://r12a.github.io/uniview/?charlist=%E3%82%A0%E3%83%BB%E3%83%BC). No idea why these are not included in the Unicode property, the chars are said to be in Katakana script *block*. So, you may actually combine the two, `[\p{Katakana}\p{Block=Katakana}]`, the `\p{Block=Katakana}` = `[\x{30A0}-\x{30FF}]`

Comment: My guess is, from my understanding, that they are not "letters"  by themselves, but rather change how the word/sentence is read. In the same vain as the western "-" changes the word, but is not an alphabet

Comment: Note that the solution might differ from regex flavor to regex flavor, in JS, you can easily see the difference between [`\p{sc=Katakana}`](https://regex101.com/r/PZzTLm/3) and [`\p{scx=Katakana}`](https://regex101.com/r/PZzTLm/2).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks, I did not know that yet. Here is a source that I have found: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Unicode_Property_Escapes

Comment: Is this a JavaScript question? Please tag accordingly.

Comment: @RyszardCzech It isn't. But it also affects Javascript, as well as PHP, as well as many other systems that use regex. But tagging these systems makes no sense. Again, its a question to "regex".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `\p{Katakana}`, `\x{30A1}-\x{30FA}\x{30FD}-\x{30FF}` is used instead of the `\x{30A0}-\x{30FF}` range, where [`\x{30A0}`, `\x{30FB}` and `\x{30FC}`](https://r12a.github.io/uniview/?charlist=%E3%82%A0%E3%83%BB%E3%83%BC) are excluded.

There is no reason these chars should not have been included because when you use `\p{Block=Katakana}` Katakana script block Unicode property class you [will match](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/list-unicodeset.jsp?a=%5B%5Cp%7BBlock%3DKatakana%7D%5D&abb=on&esc=on&g=&i=) all chars in the `\x{30A0}-\x{30FF}` range.

If you may actually combine the two, `[\p{Katakana}\p{Block=Katakana}]`, you will match all the chars you expect.

If you use ECMAScript regex flavor, the implementation is

```
\p{scx=Katakana}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dBlHsI/1). The `scx` prefix means all [indicated script extensions](https://unicode.org/reports/tr24/#Script_Extensions) are included:

> Scx set contains multiple explicit Script values; Script(cp) is implicit

and

> For example, U+30FC KATAKANA-HIRAGANA PROLONGED SOUND MARK is shared across the Hiragana and Katakana scripts, but is not used in other scripts, so it is assigned an scx set value of {Hira Kana}.